# Visual Studio (2013) C++ and MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2013

I need to make a simple C++ program in Visual Studio (2013) that connects to a MySQL database.
I have never done something like that before and a just started learning C++ a couple of weeks ago.

Please, if someone would be so kind to guide me trough this process as I couldn't find any working tutorial for this.

P.S.
I have downloaded the MySQL Connector C/C++ and installed it but i don't know how to use it or include it.

P.P.S 
I am not asking for a recommendation, but a solution on HOW to use MySQL with C++.
What do I need to download and what to setup in the project to make it work.
I know what to do after establishing the connection.

Comment: Sorry recommendations are off-topic. You can come back if you have a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: You might find [this previous Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194453/fetching-rows-in-a-mysql-database-table-using-mysql-c-api-and-c) gives you an Answer.